# yii2 - formatter currency to number

Tags: yii2

I have an input like this 500,000,000.00 named **modal**
In database, it should be 500000000.00
How can I suitable my input to database somtehing like formatter :

$this->modal = Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($this->modal);

but not works.

Please advice
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should be remove , from you number before converting to currency
you can do like it

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(str_replace(',', '',$this->modal));
```